# Issue with sending data to python flask from AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am not able to retrieve data field of AJAX in python flask.
Its shows type error when I try to retrieve data. `type` and `forwho` are of array type. When I alert them in AJAX it works.
Here is my code,

```js
// Ajax

$.ajax({
    url: '/products',
    data: JSON.stringify({'type':type,'forwho': forwho}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
        /*alert("success");*/
        $("#content").html(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        /*alert("error");*/
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

```py
# app.py

@app.route('/products', methods =['POST', 'GET'])
def all_products():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("inside all products post")
        type = json.loads(request.form.get('type'))
        forwho = json.loads(request.form.getlist('forwho'))
        print(type)
        print(forwho)
```

when I print print(request.args.get('typearr')) in all_products() it returns None

Comment: Show us the full error traceback from Python.

Comment: Maybe the use of "type" as key and value name causes the issue, as "type" is already used as key in Ajax?

Comment: In Python Flask automatically parse the JSON,   you get the request  data in JSON like that  *request.json['type']*

Comment: @IoaTzimas i tried with different names it did not work. and type is key in python not in ajax

Comment: @VasimHayat thanks but it did not work for me shows error  
    print(request.json['type'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @KlausD.
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Comment: Please add the **full** error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
type =request.json['type']
forwho = request.json['forwho']
```

Flask automatically parses JSON when having application/JSON  in your request.

Comment: it didn't work!  print(request.json.get('type'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

This solution finally worked for me.

ajax:

```````````````````
       data: JSON.stringify({'typearr':type,'forwho':forwho})

``````````````````
app.py:
#import ast
``````````````
        data = request.get_data()
        data = ast.literal_eval(data.decode("UTF-8"))
        typearr = data['typearr']
        forwho = data['forwho']
```````````````````